# Remap Apple MacBook Eject key in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, remapping, eject

I have a MacBook with Windows 7 on it as my daily driver.

My MacBook has a nearly useless eject key, but I wish it was a forward delete key. KeyRemap4Macboook works great in OS X. Is there any software that is equivalent in Windows?

I have tried KeyTweaks and HotKeys and neither of them will recognize the Eject key. I looked it up and I think it is key 161.

Is there any way to make the key into a more useful forward delete? Could I just go into the registry and do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You could install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) on windows and use the following script https://gist.github.com/nomand/9bb9fac582e2191685804c2ab96e9916. However, the script also maps the media keys for windows.